# Is it possible to sava data in an eBook on iBooks?

Tags: ios, ibooks

I have to develop an eBook for iBooks, and there's a requirement to allow the user to save data, either to local storage to be retrieved when plugged into a computer, or to upload the data to the cloud somewhere, and retrieve from a website.

I know that you can do all sorts on non-book-like things in an eBook, but I can't seem to find anything about whether this kind of data exchange is possible.

Comment: You should ask this question on the [Book Development community](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ibooks) at the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Is it just me, or are the dev forums broken?  When I go there, and click the Sign In button, sometimes nothing happens, and other times it gives me a user/pwd box, but when I fill it out, nothing happens.

Comment: It looks like the Apple Dev Forums login is totally broken, and I haven't been able to log in for days.  Now what?

Comment: Strange, I have no problem logging in. I wonder if something is screwy about your apple id? Maybe go to appleid.apple.com and see if you have any problems getting there.

Comment: Okay, I was able to get in, but I had to jump around to find the right login page.  Not sure how to explain it.  Anyway, I asked the question there.  I hope they're as helpful as here on SO!

Comment: But unfortunately, no one has answered the question there.  Sigh.

Comment: Where did you post it? I don't see any recent questions in the Book Development forum.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4591259

Comment: That's actually different than what I posted. That's an Apple Support community. I didn't even realize there was one for books. Unless I'm mistaken, that community is basically just going to get answers from other customers/developers. The link I posted is for the Book Development community on the Apple Developer forums, where you can actually get answers from Apple engineers.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference.  Unfortunately, I still can't log into the dev site.  I checked my AppleId, deleted all my cookies for apple.com, and still, when I get to the dev forums, it asks for a login and then dumps me back to the sign in page.  Very annoying.